# Formula for a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, matlab, closed-form

I am looking for a formula $y_i = f(i, \kappa)$, for $i=1...K$ data points, that generates a convex function like this one:

[image]

The function should contain a parameter, e.g. $\kappa$ that can handle the amount of convexity. Ideally, setting this parameter to a certain value should give equal weights (e.g. $y_i = y_j$ for all $i=1...K$)

Comment: Are $y_i$ data points? Is so, they are given and the property of adding up to 1 is either given or not.

Comment: No $y$ is not given. $x_i$ is just 1...K. Maybe I should rewrite it as $y_i = f(i, \kappa)$

Answer (score 1):

You can combine basic convex functions, e.g.
$$y_1(x) = \sum_{i=1}^K (x-i)^2$$
and then renormalise them to obtain
$$y(x) = \frac{y_1(x)}{\sum_{i=1}^K y_1(i)}$$

Comment: Makes sense. How do I include the convexity parameter?

Comment: @JohnAndrews depends on what you want exactly. You could try with weighting the terms in the sum, or scaling using $(cx-i)$, or increasing the powers to $(x-i)^{2+c}$ (for $c>0$), or in a million other ways. I'd go with the first option.

Comment: For which c can I have that all y_i are equal?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the difference between x and i in your function.

Comment: If you are scaling $x$, then for $c=0$ the function $y(x)$ is constant.

Comment: Here $x$ is a function argument. The $i$ is just an index over which we sum the terms.

Comment: Oke. But I would like to use the index $i$ only to generate a convex function as shown above.